# integration react-native layout abnormal

Tags: ios, react-native

I follow [this tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content) and successfully build simple ListView app which depend on css [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), the UI looks well the same to official img below(**left one**).

now I have exist native app which implements by objective c logic, and I try to integrate above code, but I find that messy layout UI appear, some space at the bottom and text looks in a mess, like below img(**right one**).

my objective-c side code is same to [Integrating with Existing Apps](https://github.com/tjwudi/EmbededReactNativeExample) from official doc, and I replace `ReactComponents/index.ios.js` code from [react-native-ListView-demo](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#final-source-code)

er.. I don't understand how to fix it, I don't modify any code while previous display looks great.

also reuse origin css layout style

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 8,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  year: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
  listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

could anyone help me?

thanks..

[image]
[image]

Comment: *don't understand how to fix it* ... too broad for us to help. Please show your codes.

Comment: @Raptor  thanks for your time, I update some explanation which include source code, could you have a look in free time?  regards..